# Is there a way to issue next (like INSERT) mysql statment inside the mysql_fetch_row() loop?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a problem as I would like to fill a table_B based on row(s) retrieved from table_A.

```
if (mysql_query(conn,"Select X,Y,Z from table_A;")) {
        die_mysql_err();
} 
else 
{
    res = mysql_use_result(conn);
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {

             >> HERE I would like to INSERT some data into the table_B.
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);
}
```

The error message is:

```
 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I understand the message but do not know what would be the best solution ..

- Should I create another connection? What about time/speed and resources then ?
- Can I solve it (how??) with mysql_store_result() function ?

Both tables are in the same database.

Comment: do your fetching, cache into a data structure, then run your inserts separately after the fetching query has been closed?

Comment: It's one of the solutions. But looking for something like storing the result set on kind of the stack, could be the mysql_store_result() do the trick but can not find any example on how to do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Should I create another connection?

Yes, you can do this.

> What about time/speed and resources then ?

Not bad, as long as you don't close and reopen the second connection for every row.

> Can I solve it (how??) with mysql_store_result() function ?

You can loop over your first resultset and store all the results in an array in memory, then free it, then loop over the array doing your inserts.

Have you considered that you could do this sort of thing instead?

```
 INSERT INTO Table_B (x, y, z, a)
 SELECT x,y,z, x+y+z AS a
   FROM table_a
```

If your required computations on the rows of table a can be represented in SQL you can do this in a single query.

Comment: So it seems (from both answers) the only way is to build a temporary array/list/queue etc ...